# How to use SignalR via Ngnix Reverse SSL Proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nginx, ssl, signalr

I'm trying to config a web api with SignalR enabled, so I can push real-time information to the clients via websockets. In front of the api I have a nginx reverse ssl proxy running in a docker container.

Clients can connect just fine via the reverse proxy when ssl is disabled in the nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 55555;
    # listen 55555 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /config/keys/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /config/keys/cert.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.175:50000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

But when I configure the proxy to listen for ssl the clients can't seem to connect, or at least the client gets a "The server disconnected before the handshake could be started" IOException after what appears to be a time out.

WebAPI log:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.1.150/chatHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 - 0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint '/chatHub/negotiate'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionManager[1]
      New connection i-HjjQP9EsA_rBTX7vFs2Q created.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionDispatcher[10]
      Sending negotiation response.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint '/chatHub/negotiate'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.1.150/chatHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 - 0 - 200 316 application/json 117.3988ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.1.150/chatHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 - 0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint '/chatHub/negotiate'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionManager[1]
      New connection K0y7OI3-3KvPIXWV92HEkA created.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionDispatcher[10]
      Sending negotiation response.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint '/chatHub/negotiate'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.1.150/chatHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 - 0 - 200 316 application/json 11.6330ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://192.168.1.150/chatHub?id=zdDUpBZ-RsnQgEZsJ9Sctg - -
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint '/chatHub'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionDispatcher[4]
      Establishing new connection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler[5]
      OnConnectedAsync started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext[2]
      Handshake was canceled.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionManager[2]
      Removing connection zdDUpBZ-RsnQgEZsJ9Sctg from the list of connections.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint '/chatHub'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://192.168.1.150/chatHub?id=zdDUpBZ-RsnQgEZsJ9Sctg - - - 200 - text/event-stream 60079.4344ms
```

I've tried including the following in the WebApplication settings:

```
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.150")); // Proxy Server IP
});

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost
});
```

But as far as I can tell, it doesn't really make a difference.

I'm unsure whether this is a nginx reverse proxy/sll or a Webpi/SignalR issue. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Have you found a solution?